# Switch with If Statement Inside for Java ATM Project

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, logic

Right now I am working on an `ATM` project. 
The user will input their name, balance, type of transaction, and the transaction amount. The types of transactions are `Withdraw (W)`, `Deposit (D)` and `R (Report)`, I am using a `switch`, with 3 `cases` `W`, `D`, `R`. The program will output an error if you: Input a wrong code, you don't have enough funds to do the type of transaction you selected, and the amount you entered is negative. Right now I am stumped trying to setup the `switch`. My code is below and any help would be appreciated! Thanks

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class atmValidator {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String fname = " ", lname = " ";

      double balbefore = 0.0, balafter = 0.0, transamount = 0.0;

      char code = ' ';

      Scanner screen = null;
      FileInputStream fis = null;
      FileOutputStream fos = null;
      PrintWriter pw = null;

      //Declaring the variables/scanner/etc.

      try {
        fis = new FileInputStream ("transactions.txt");
        fos = new FileOutputStream ("statement.txt");

        screen = new Scanner (fis);
        pw = new PrintWriter (fos);

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("File not found");
          System.exit(0);
      }

      //The try/catch for reading from the file

      while (screen.hasNext()) {
        fname = screen.next();
        lname = screen.next();
        balbefore = screen.nextDouble();
        code = screen.next().charAt(0);
        transamount = screen.nextInt();

      //A while loop to gather the info from the file, and the variables getting their values from the files.

        switch (code) {

            case 'D':
                balafter = balbefore + transamount;
                if (transamount <0) {
                    pw.println("ERROR: Enter positive amount.");
                }
                else if (balafter < 300) {
                    pw.println("Warning, balance below $300");
                }

                {

                   // Where I am stuck at :(   
                }
          }
       }        
       screen.close();
       pw.close();

    }   
}
//Sorry for the weird braces and spaces
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there! After each case, you need to follow up with `break;` and move onto the next `case`. And at the very end, you need to have a `default: break`, which translates to "If the variable doesn't fit any of the cases, then break out of the switch".

So switch works like the following:

```
switch(code) {
    case 'D': 
        // do deposit code
        break;
    case 'W':
        // do withdrawl code
        break;
    ...
    default:
        break;
}
```

Switch has a different syntax in that it doesn't have curly braces to define the block of the code. It rather looks for that `break;` and the following `case:` or `default:` to move on.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html has good examples for you to follow.

**Edit after comment:**

In response to your comment, you would need to do the following:

```
case 'W':
    tempBal = balbefore - transamount;
    if(tempBal < 0) {
        System.out.println("Insufficient Funds");
    }
    else {
        balafter = balbefore - transamount;
        if(balafter < 300) {
            System.out.println("Warning, balance below $300");
        }
    }
    break;
...
default:
    System.out.println("Please select "D", "W", or "R");
    break;
```

Comment: I edited my answer. You can pretty much do anything you want inside of case. You can do the validation checks before printing out `balafter`.

Comment: Yeah. I explained that confusingly, if someone entered a code like Y, how could I create a switch that would output an error.

Comment: Would I be required to do a case for every wrong code(Basically every letter besides W,D,R) or is there a better way?

Comment: Well is there any other error messages you would like to print out for other options? Usually withdrawing should give the error as you could be in danger of having negative balance or low balance. But I don't think depositing more money into your account should result in an error message.

Comment: I edited my answer to show what you would need to do. Basically, you don't even want to let the user take out money if `balbefore - transamount` is going to result in negatives. But if it clears that condition, you can go ahead and do the transaction but right afterwards, check if the `balafter` is less than 300 and if it is, print out the warning message. Then you can go ahead and break.

Comment: Right so this is where I'm at. I changed the code above. I have transamount<0~Error that user is entering negative numbers which isnt allowed. And balafter<0~Warning balance is below 300. I just need one more error and it is if the user enters a code that is not (D,W,R). Other than that I'm good!

Comment: Oh I see. Edited my answer. You just need to add the statement on `default:`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Would I have that same default statement in each of my cases?

Comment: In each switch statement, `default` is needed at the very end. It's like having `if` and `else`. When nothing matches any of the cases, turn to the `default`. So not inside each cases but inside each switch statement.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes so much sense. So if it goes through the code and it does not match, it "defaults" to the default and says "enter a valid code" because the inputted letter is not the same as the case letters. Thanks so much for the help all!

Comment: No problem! If it helped, could you accept my answer?

Comment: I think I did it, if not tell me what to do (Im new to this site)

Answer (score 1):

You can write the cases as below inside the switch body. You can elongate the conditions even more but here I just gave you an example of how to do. If the character is other than D, W or R, the default case will be executed.

```
    switch (code) {
        case 'D':
            balafter = balbefore + transamount;
            System.out.println("");
            if (balafter < 0) {
                pw.println("Insufficent funds");

            } else if (balafter < 300) {
                pw.println("Warning, balance below $300");
            }else{
                pw.println("Well. You have now " + balafter + "$");
            }
            break;
        case 'W':
            balafter = balbefore - transamount;
            if (transamount > balbefore) {
                pw.println("Sorry. You don't enough funds.");

            } else if (transamount <= balbefore && balafter < 300) {
                pw.println("Warning, balance below $300");
            } else {
                pw.println("The withdrawl was successful.");
            }
            break;
        case 'R':
            balafter = balbefore + transamount;
            if (balafter < 0) {
                pw.println("Insufficent funds");

            } else if (balafter < 300) {
                pw.println("Warning, balance below $300");
            } else {
                pw.println("Good. Your balance is " + balAfter);
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Nothing to do.");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Would've been more challenging if he figured it out through the use of our guides, not by doing it ourselves. :/